# Where can I find the 'psk' referred to in the Breakout Arduino Library examples?

Tags: twilio

I am trying to test my Seeed Wio LTE board per the instructions here:  https://github.com/twilio/Breakout_Arduino_Library#retrieve-psk-from-console-and-assign-psk-in-client

I'm logged into my Twilio Console (https://www.twilio.com/console/wireless/sims) but there is nothing labeled 'psk' nor anything that appears to be the right size.  If I select my SIM there is an "SID" and "SIM ICCID" but they do not appear to be the correct size.

In the code example it states:

```
/** Change this to your key for the SIM card inserted in this device 
 *  You can find your PSK under the Breakout SDK tab of your Narrowband SIM detail at
 *  https://www.twilio.com/console/wireless/sims
*/
static const char *psk_key = "00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff";
```

It appears they have changed the Console ... where do I get the 'psk' or what value am I supposed to be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The tutorial in that GitHub repo was temporary during an early release preview of the dev kit.

Since then we have improved mechanisms for achieving the same thing that are launching in the next few days. This is why the console has changed and the PSK has gone away.

If you are interested in the latest iteration of the project feel free to email me at philnash@twilio.com and I will connect you with the Wireless team here for a sneak peek.